# Is it possible to include a NodeJS module in a TypeScript Project with "import"

Tags: express, typescript

I am converting my NodeJS + ExpressJS project to typescript and I got a Typescript definition for ExpressJS from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped.

Before Typescript I imported Express with a "require" statement

```
var express = require("express")
```

No I need to import it in way that I can use Typescript Syntax and capabilities while ensuring that the Typescript compiler compiles it to the statement shown above. Here's the code I wrote:

```
/// <reference path="express.d.ts" />
import express = require("express");
var app = express.express();
app.use(express.logger());
```

This however throws the error: `Unresolved function or method express()` at:

```
var app = express.express();
```

Comment: Does the definition file not already declare an `express` namespace? Maybe this is causing a naming clash?

Comment: The express namespace is there. But doesn't have an express() function inside it. I've added that manually and seems to work for now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that should be :

```
import express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

See example : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/express/express-tests.ts#L3-L4

Comment: Hi, You pointed me to "express-tests.ts" and I'm using "express.d.ts". Whats the difference? Which one should I add to my project? I got this working eventually but I had to add the "express()" function manually to express.d.ts file.

Comment: You should import `express.d.ts`. The file `express-tests.ts` shows you how you can use `express.d.ts` in your own application.